# Display out my images stored in Firebase Storage by referring to the lists of image paths in my Firestore Database

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

[image]

So, I have this document that contains a list of image path that its file have been stored inside Firebase Storage. So my problem here is, how can I use future builder to load out all the images.

I have try to display out a single file with this method and its works but I just cant connect the way to display out all the file by using Future Builder.

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: storage.downloadURL(annData.imagePath),
   builder: (BuildContext context,
       AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)
  {
     return Container(
       width: 200,
       height: 200,
        child: InteractiveViewer(
           child: AspectRatio(
             aspectRatio: 1,
               child: ClipRRect(
                 child: Image.network(
                  snapshot.data!,
                   fit: BoxFit.contain,
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
       );
   }
   if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
   {
       return Loading();
   }
     return Container();
  },
),
```

And this is my downloadURL method

```
Future<String> downloadURL(String imagePath) async {
  String downloadURL = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('test/$imagePath').getDownloadURL();

  return downloadURL;
}
```

My imagePath in database is a List.

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem in this code, but that could well be because we're missing context here. Did you already put a breakpoint inside your `downloadURL` method and run in the debugger to check what the value of `imagePath` is, and what `downloadURL` it then returns?

Comment: The value of imagePath taken from database will be something like an array. So i know that we can use listview.builder for array like data but im not sure how to get data like this ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'] and use it in a future builder. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: can you check this link -https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-storage-in-flutter-9f23b04291e5

Comment: If you have an array of image paths, you'll want to loop over those and generate a separate `FutureBuilder` for each of them.

Comment: So I will be looping future builder inside a listview builder ?

Comment: I did it, thanks for the insight. Why didnt i think of it in the first place to swap future builder inside listview.builder. THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Frank van Puffelen,If you have an array of image paths, you'll want to loop over those and generate a separate FutureBuilder for each of them.